# How to add some days to str_to_date mysql function?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table in which i have a string date which was in the format of `01.04.2015`. Now I want to add some days to that string date format column. For this I have below query to add some days.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(level2,INTERVAL 28 DAY) level2 FROM  sales_purchase_stocks_hs WHERE stock= '123'
```

When I run this query I am getting wrong date out put. The out put is `2001-05-18 15:00:00`. But my original date string was `01.04.2015` (April 1st 2015).

I tried with the below query

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_ADD(level2,INTERVAL 28 DAY),'%d.%m.%Y') level2 FROM  sales_purchase_stocks_hs WHERE stock = '123'.
```

But when I run the query I am getting `null` as result. Can any one please help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is hard to help with a bad design. Store dates in canonical form always. Output them in the format the user wants (every language has date formatting functions). This is a Truth of Good Programming. (Please excuse the pomposity.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You need to first convert the string date to real date using `str_to_date` and then apply `date_add()` on it.

Here how `str_to_date` works

```
mysql> select str_to_date('01.04.2015','%d.%m.%Y') as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-04-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now use the above inside the `date_add()` so you have

```
mysql> select date_add(str_to_date('01.04.2015','%d.%m.%Y'),interval 28 day) as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-04-29 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You now can use the above in the query.

Comment: HI, can you please look at this one?how-to-tell-mysql-to-skip-a-column-if-it-is-empty-or-null-with-out-processing

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`your_field_name`, INTERVAL 28 DAY)....
```

For example I am adding 10 days here,

```
mysql> select date_start from date_of_join where id = 23 ;
+------------+
| date_start |
+------------+
| 2012-02-03 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD(`date_start`, INTERVAL 10 DAY) from date_of_join where id = 23 ;
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(`date_start`, INTERVAL 10 DAY) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2012-02-13                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is this a question? or an answer? if an answer, explain why should they try this

Comment: I was trying to explain that the DATE_ADD perfectly works even without str_to_date. See example in my answer below works if field type is date. 'yyyy-mm-dd'